# MongoDB Official Docker Image Init Scripts Not Running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

mongo image version:4.2

```
version: "3"

services:
    mongo:
        image: blazehub/mongo
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
            - ./init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: 'admin'
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "admin"
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
        networks:
            - overlay

networks:
    overlay:
```

It the init scripts i have never being called while running the container

After debugging a bit i found a snippet in docker-entrypoint.sh

```
# check for a few known paths (to determine whether we've already initialized and should thus skip our initdb scripts)

if [ -n "$shouldPerformInitdb" ]; then
    dbPath="$(_dbPath "$@")"
    for path in \
        "$dbPath/WiredTiger" \
        "$dbPath/journal" \
        "$dbPath/local.0" \
        "$dbPath/storage.bson" \
    ; do
        if [ -e "$path" ]; then
            shouldPerformInitdb=
            break
        fi
    done
fi
```

after mongo started i never see local.0 file being created

please suggest the fix or if anything missing as part of setup.

Comment: Are you starting from a brand new install with an empty /data/db volume ? Nothing will play if there is already a db in there.

Comment: Note: the above is also taking for granted that you are using an image based on the official mongodb docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) which is not 100% clear from your post.

Comment: yes it is brand new container with empty directory. the above code snippet is from mongo official image, since the one of the directory doesnt exist , the script do not invoke the db-init scripts or create the INIT_DB_USERS in ENV

Comment: Did you check for any errors in the container's log ?

Comment: container is running fine...but but scripts and user creation is not working as given in environment

Comment: Do all files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` have the `.sh` or `.js` extension as advised in the doc? `Runing fine...` is not the answer to my previous question: did you check the **entire** startup log for any evidence of possible initialization problems that would explain what you are experiencing? (e.g. messages like `ignoring init-file-XXXX`). And ultimately, did you try with the original official image rather that your custom one? Are you sure the problem does not come from your customizations (that you do not show at all)?

Comment: all file are their in directory. Also i am running official mongo image only, its just for debug purpose i pointed the script which run as entry point in official image and need checks it has for executing the init_scripts